# how to check returned response string value using Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to check the response values of a `Vue` API request.
I tried with `resp.data == "-1"`.but it is not working. Please help me to how to check response value in `vue js`.

vue js function:

```
          callback: function () {
            this.$http
              .post(`/api/food-item/${data.ItemId}/delete`)
              .then((resp) => {
                if(resp.data == "-1")
                {
                  ShowError(this.$toast, "Used Items!!");
                }
                else
                {
                  ShowSuccess(this.$toast, "Food item deleted successfully");
                  resp.data;
                  self.$nextTick(function () {
                    self.$refs.vuetable.refresh();
                  });
                }
                
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                const errorMsg = error.response.data.ExceptionMessage;
                ShowError(this.$toast, errorMsg);
              });
          },
```

c# code:

```
        [Route("{foodItemId}/delete")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Delete(int foodItemId)
        {
            if (!foodItemService.IsExist(foodItemId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (foodItemService.IsUsed(foodItemId))
            {
                return Ok("-1");    //this line is the return line
            }

            foodItemService.Delete(foodItemId);
            return Ok();
        }
```

Error in the terminal:

```
  312:19  error  Replace `(resp.data·==·"-1")␍⏎···············` with `·(resp.data·==·"-1")`  prettier/prettier
  315:18  error  Replace `␍⏎················else␍⏎···············` with `·else`              prettier/prettier
  323:18  error  Delete `␍⏎················`                                                 prettier/prettier
```

Comment: something doesn't like `␍⏎` for some reason (that's not the issue though)

Comment: which library are you using for `this.$http` ... you tagged `axios` but never seem to use it, instead you seem to be using something that looks like an angular concept

Comment: @JaromandaX he is using Vue Resource https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: so why did he tag `axios` :p @deaponn

Comment: angular-based library I used here

Comment: why using angular based library in vue project?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Vue Resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) Github documentation, you need to use `response.body` instead of `response.data`:

```
if(resp.body == "-1") {
    ShowError(this.$toast, "Used Items!!");
}
```

Comment: of course, you are assuming `this.$http` is like `fetch`, and not like `axios` or the angular `$http` - even though it looks nothing like fetch, and more like axios or $http

Comment: Yes you are right I need to change my answer

Comment: This does not work for me. It fire else part.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to resolve your issue. What library exactly are you using?